# how much percentage of resources are used by kube-master from kube-minion for spawning pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to add new minion to my existing k8s cluster. I am wondering about how much percentage of added resources are actually used by k8s master for spawning pods ?

Comment: What does the manual says?

Comment: I searched but didn't find it.

Comment: Are you asking how many pods can the master support? As of 1.2 release, k8s claims to support 1000 nodes and 30,000 pods. See this [blog](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/1000-nodes-and-beyond-updates-to-Kubernetes-performance-and-scalability-in-12.html)

Comment: yah..thats fine...but I am looking for the CPU and RAM ?...Anyway, I found some info related to resource reservation at kubernetes.io/docs/admin/node/  .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the pod management overhead on individual nodes, i.e., how much cpu/memory it takes for the per-node agent/daemon to run N pods for you on that node. This is different from the "master node" which usually runs a few master components/pods.

The resource usage depends on many factors. To name a few, the container runtime (e.g, docker/rkt) and its version/configuration, the number of the pods, the type of pods, and so on. To present users a better picture of the kubernetes per-node overhead, there is an on-going effort to create a node benchmark to let you profile the performance and resource usage on your node.

For now, you can check the [k8s perf dashboard](http://perf-dash.k8s.io/) and select "kubelet perf 100" from the drop down menu to see what's the resource usage of kubelet (the node agent) and docker for managing a 100 "do-nothing" pods on the node. It should be noted that this is the *best* case (i.e., steady state) where no pod operations (creation/deletion) are performed. You are expected to see cpu spikes when there are multiple concurrent operations (e.g., creating 30 pods).